# How to get namespace, class, methods and its arguments with Reflection

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, types

I need to load the `dll` using `reflection` and have to get the `namespace`, `class`, `methods` and its `arguments` for that `dll`. Also, I need to write those information in  a log file.

I have used the following code. But I got only up to class that has been written to log file.

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\Assemblies\Myapplication.dll");
foreach (Type type in dll.GetTypes())
{
    var name = "Myapplication~" + type.FullName;
    File.AppendAllText("Assembly Details.log", "Myapplication~" + type.FullName + "\r\n\r\n");

    Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
}
```

In the log file, the information needs to written as below.

```
Myapplication~namespace.class~method(arguments)
```

Eg:

> Myapplication~copyassembly.class~Mymethod(String, Type)

Any suggestions would be greatly helpful.

Comment: Type's FullName contains the namespace. You only need to split the FullName apart to the namespace. To get methods, try [Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d848zkb(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can write a code similar to this

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"C:\YourDirectory\YourAssembly.dll");

foreach (Type type in dll.GetTypes())
{
    var details = string.Format("Namespace : {0}, Type : {1}", type.Namespace, type.Name);
    //write details to your log file here...
    Console.WriteLine(details);

    foreach (var method in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public))
    {
        var methodDetails = string.Format("{0} {1}({2})", method.ReturnParameter, method.Name, 
                                            string.Join(",", method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name)));
        //write methodDetails to your log file here...
        Console.WriteLine("\t" + methodDetails);
    }
}
```

Which will write these details

```
Namespace : MyNamespace.Helpers, Type : Constants
    System.String  ToString()
    Boolean  Equals(Object)
    Int32  GetHashCode()
    System.Type  GetType()
Namespace : MyNamespace.Helpers, Type : FileHelper
    Void  WriteToFile(String,String,String,String)
    Void  UpdateFile(String,String,Boolean)
```

Here, you might [1] change the `BindingFlags` as per your need [2] change format of the log string (details/methodDetails) [3] format collection/generic types as you need

**Edit**
If you want to display without the return type, simply format it like

```
var methodDetails = string.Format("{1}({2})", 
                                  method.Name, 
                                  string.Join(",", method.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name)));
```

Answer (score 3):

For public method

```
 MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

For Non-Public Methods

```
 MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo1 = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance|BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
```

and then extract information using

```
 MethodInfo[] myArrayMethodInfo

// Display information for all methods.
for(int i=0;i<myArrayMethodInfo.Length;i++)
{
    MethodInfo myMethodInfo = (MethodInfo)myArrayMethodInfo[i];
    Console.WriteLine("\nThe name of the method is {0}.",myMethodInfo.Name);

    ParameterInfo[] pars = myMethodInfo.GetParameters();
    foreach (ParameterInfo p in pars) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.ParameterType);
    }
}
```

Comment: MethodInfo will contain all methods for particular type. its up to you what information you want to extract.

Comment: @ManoRoshan see my edited answer, that should help you. Additionally, you can tag people like @<username> to grab their attention.

Answer (score 1):

Using a sort of LINQ its possible to do this in this way

```
var dll = Assembly.LoadFile(@"D:\Trabalho\Temp\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\ConsoleApplication1.exe");

var logItems = dll.GetTypes()
    .SelectMany(t => t.GetMethods(), Tuple.Create)
    .OrderBy(t => t.Item1.Namespace)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Item1.Name)
    .ThenBy(t => t.Item2.Name)
    .Select(t => $"{"ConsoleApplication1"}~{t.Item1.FullName}~{t.Item2.Name}({string.Join(", ", t.Item2.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType.Name))})");

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, logItems));
```

And then this output

> ConsoleApplication1~MyNamespace.Program~Equals(Object)
>
> ConsoleApplication1~MyNamespace.Program~GetHashCode()
>
> ConsoleApplication1~MyNamespace.Program~GetType()
>
> ConsoleApplication1~MyNamespace.Program~Main(String[])
>
> ConsoleApplication1~MyNamespace.Program~ToString()

Then you can save it in file

```
File.AppendAllLines("Assembly Details.log", logItems);
```

Comment: Thanks Arghya and Alberto. @Arghya how to get the overloaded methods also in the above codes

Comment: @ManoRoshan this code already get overloaded methods, se my output test